render math equations in doc strings in online documentation
Can mdbook be used to render equations in Rust doc strings?  Like, I get that I can used it in book.toml in an mdbook, but can I use it in a rust crate somehow? Is there some other reasonable way to render equations in doc strings?

I've just seen you asked a very similar question last year. It seems you expect what mdbook supports to be supported by rustdoc which is (unfortunately) not the case.
